# How often should my app update user's location using GPS? Is every 1 second overkill or fine?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

Using google maps api to create a route while the app is open.

right now, I am updating every second.  is this fine?  how often does the google maps app update for example?  Does it kill the battery/hog the CPU if I have the location updated every 1 second?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a second is fine.
You cannot save battery by updating once in 5 seconds.
To save battery you have to request in a much lower frequence, like once in 20 minutes.

It depends of your application how accurate the tracking must be and how often you need a location.

Comment: Thanks.  I need it to be accurate enough so I can save the gps co-ordinates and share the route, so I guess 1 second will cover all bases.  I think in a car @ 60 this would be what.. every 90 feet?  I will fiddle with it more next time I go with my mom for a drive.

Comment: just transform the velocity to meters per second. Then you get the distance between the two location. It will be about 20m for normal speeds.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how precise your app should be. It is true, that having a short delay drains battery, but if you want to track user's movement precisely, you have no choice. Try to approximately check GPS interval of some similar tracking apps, but I think that many of them just keep GPS turned on.

Play with it and you will find the ideal configuration for your desired app. :-)

Comment: Thanks.  What I did was compute average speeds in MPH and see how much distance they would cover in 1 second.  My plan in the future (maybe this weekend) is to maybe for the first 15 seconds see how far the user has traveled.  Depending on the average speed during that time, I will make it maybe every 5 seconds for users who are traveling short distances, and every 1 second for those who are traveling > 40 mph.  I went for a short car ride and was using my mom's Razr and did not really notice any less battery drain with updates every 1 second.